# Spring boot API RESTful: error handling problem with requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, handlerexceptionresolver

I'm building a RESTful API with Spring boot, but I have a problem when I try to handle errors concerning requests.

GetUserById (code) :

```
 @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable("id") int idUser) throws UserIntrouvaleException {
        User userFind =  service.getUserById(idUser);
        if(userFind == null){
            throw new UserIntrouvaleException("The user with the ID "+idUser+"does not exist !");
        }
        return userFind;
    }
```

UserIntrouvaleException (code) :

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class UserIntrouvaleException extends RuntimeException {
    public UserIntrouvaleException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

Error :

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:148) ~[na:na]
    at dashboard.project.service.UserServiceImpl.getUserById(UserServiceImpl.java:33) ~[main/:na]
    at dashboard.project.controller.ApiRestController.getUserById(ApiRestController.java:32) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
```

Comment: object not found against the userId, u need to handle it in service layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Optional, try checking if optional returned has any value using optional.isPresent() and then perform any oprations on the optional.

Would be helpful if you could add the logic in service.getUserById()

Comment: @RoarS. And why do you want to return null if user doesn’t exist?

Comment: @Rana_S: Maybe I was a little bit too quick on this one, without source for `UserServiceImpl`, it is hard to tell. BR